# Set up wildcard subdomain reverse proxy on Apache 2.4.7

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

Running a project right now that requires serving a particular page to all hits to any subdomain. This must work as a (reverse?) proxy, not as a redirect.

**Overview**

Several (tens and possibly hundreds of thousands) of users will have a URL set up for them like so:

```
(some_user_name).example.tld
```

Example: `john_smith_123.example.tld`.

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 14.04 Apache 2.4.7
- HTML / CSS / JS
- No server-side scripts (allowed)

**Requirements**

1. When visiting `(some_user_name).example.tld`, all users must see the same content (a web form that has code to parse the subdomain value) which is located at `example.tld/directory/sub-directory/`. Inside the sub-directory in that path, we have an `index.html` (that should be served by default) and a `thank-you.html` file that should be served upon form submission (a confirmation page).
2. On that index.html page, we have js code to parse out the subdomain value and do magic to show some content personalized to that user. It will work as long as the subdomain is present in the address bar.
3. We also have some js that must be able to load resources by referencing assets located in the root domain (`example.tld/assets/js/main.js`, for example).
4. Upon form submission, we want to show the user this address in the address bar `(some_user_name).example.tld/thank-you` that shows content from `example.tld/directory/sub-directory/thank-you.html`

So, this is right:

- User goes to `(some_user_name).example.tld` -> user sees page content from `example.tld/directory/sub-directory/index.html` while the address bar still displays `(some_user_name).example.tld`
- User then submits the form (presumably) and sees `(some_user_name).example.tld/thank-you`

This is wrong:

- (some_user_name).example.tld -> redirects to
  example.tld/directory/sub-directory/index.html (showing in the address
  bar).

**Solutions?**

We've been digging for and trying answers (including searching and attempting several stack overflow answers), but quite meet the requirements and we're at an impasse.

Here are some of the solutions we attempted:

- [Setting up Wildcard subdomain (with reverse proxy) on apache 2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187289/setting-up-wildcard-subdomain-with-reverse-proxy-on-apache-2-2-3)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/644648/how-to-configure-and-combine-wildcard-domains-and-subdomains-in-apache2s-virtua
- Several others (outside stack overflow) like Apache documentation and other sites.

So far, we encountered some issues that seem common across documented solutions (as well as our own attempts). We tried several (really, 2-3 different variations of several implementations).

So, to keep this short, here are the last two attempts:

**Here's the closest we've come:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine On

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mailfunnel.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/direct-mail/personal-debt-settlement/
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine On

</VirtualHost>
```

This shows the right html content, but all js/css is broken (since those are coded as relative links like `/assets/js/main.js`, for example).

We don't want to use absolute URLs because this page content may be served on dev and uat environments (as well as production).

Furthermore, while we could copy that assets folder, we prefer not to duplicate & maintain code in two places.

**And here's the non-working setup we had tried just before it:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.example\.com/(.*)$
    RewriteRule (.*)    "http://example.com/directory/sub-directory/" [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

But, `(any_subdomain).example.tld` returns a 404 page.

Changing

```
RewriteRule (.*)    "http://example.com/directory/sub-directory/" [P]
```

to

```
RewriteRule (.*)    "http://example.com/directory/sub-directory/index.html" [P]
```

results in a redirect to `http://example.com/directory/sub-directory/index` (showing the resulting full path in the address bar) and a "Not Found - The requested URL /directory/sub-directory/index was not found on the server" error.

Removing the `.html` from `index.html` results in the same 404 page as before.

---

Thoughts?